# Maos 10.13.1 High Sierra: unable to start proftpd

Tags: macos, homebrew, ftp

I just upgrades to 10.13 and I need a ftp server.

I installed proftpd with homebrew.

brew services start proftpd (or sudo brew services start proftpd)
says:

==> Successfully started `proftpd` (label: homebrew.mxcl.proftpd)

But I am not able to FTP-in from another machine.

I also tried svftp with the same result, so it is probably not a proftpd issue but the way the service is started.

What did I miss in enabling ftp to work?